# What is C and S constructs with respect to entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

In Entity Framework 6 source code there is a comment on [EntitySetBase](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Metadata/Edm/EntitySetBase.cs) class

> Possible Future Enhancement: revisit factoring of EntitySetBase and delta between C constructs and S constructs
>
> Currently, we need to have a way to map an entityset or a relationship
>   set in S space to the appropriate structures in the store. In order to
>   address this we said we would add new ItemAttributes (tableName,
>   schemaName and catalogName to the EntitySetBase)...  problem with this
>   is that we are bleading a leaf-level, store specific set of constructs
>   into the object model for things that may exist at either C or S.
>
> We need to do this for now to push forward on enabling the conversion
>   but we need to re-examine whether we should have separate C and S
>   space constructs or some other mechanism for  maintaining this
>   metadata.

What does **delta between C constructs and S constructs** mean ?

Comment: may be the `Conceptual Schema Definition Language` and the `Store Schema Definition Language`. **CSDL** and **SSDL** form the core of `Entity Framework` and are linked by `Mapping Specification Language`.